# Unable to create OpenStack external network

Tags: networking, external, openstack, provider

I have OpenStack running in a virtual machine. The installation script populated the networks with a shared and public network. The public network has value which came from the script and are not for my provider network.

I tried to follow the directions on this page to create a network that would use my internal network as the provider network so I could associated instances with a floating ip that would allow external access.

https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/launch-instance-networks-provider.html

When I get to the first command in the guide:

```
openstack network create  --share --external   --provider-physical-network provider   --provider-network-type flat provider
```

I get this error:

```
Error while executing command: BadRequestException: 400, Invalid input for operation: physical_network 'provider' unknown for flat provider network
```

I googled around for a solution but I couldn't find anything that addressed this particular error output. I must not be understanding something fundamental about OpenStack and networks. Any help or links to guides would be appreciated!

Per the guide I am following I expected the following:

Created a new network:

```
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                     | Value                                |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up            | UP                                   |
| availability_zone_hints   |                                      |
| availability_zones        |                                      |
| created_at                | 2017-03-14T14:37:39Z                 |
| description               |                                      |
| dns_domain                | None                                 |
| id                        | 54adb94a-4dce-437f-a33b-e7e2e7648173 |
| ipv4_address_scope        | None                                 |
| ipv6_address_scope        | None                                 |
| is_default                | None                                 |
| mtu                       | 1500                                 |
| name                      | provider                             |
| port_security_enabled     | True                                 |
| project_id                | 4c7f48f1da5b494faaa66713686a7707     |
| provider:network_type     | flat                                 |
| provider:physical_network | provider                             |
| provider:segmentation_id  | None                                 |
| qos_policy_id             | None                                 |
| revision_number           | 3                                    |
| router:external           | External                             |
| segments                  | None                                 |
| shared                    | True                                 |
| status                    | ACTIVE                               |
| subnets                   |                                      |
| updated_at                | 2017-03-14T14:37:39Z                 |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you have a mapping for the virtual provider network and the physical network interface as mentioned in the `linuxbridge_agent.ini` file? In the section `[linux_bridge]` (if you use linuxbridge) there should be something similar to this: `physical_interface_mappings = provider:eth1`

Comment: in my case the physical NIC is name ens18 (its a VM I am running this on) so I entered physical_interface_mappings = provider:ens18 . Does that make sense or should I be using eth1 (maybe that was just an example).

Comment: Yes, eth1 is just an example. After you restarted the neutron services, are they up and running? Can you share `openstack network agent list`? Also does the ml2_conf.ini contain the `flat_networks = provider` as @katonalala already mentioned?

Comment: That worked! It was missing the provider value in the flat_networks variable. Unfortunately, something else got hosed up and I am starting from scratch but now I have this information to help me. Thank you both for your assistance. Ultimately, as I mention in my OP, I want to be able to allow access from the private openstack network instances are connected to, to my home network so I can ssh in and do maintenance as a learning exercise.

Comment: According to the rules I might need to start a new thread, but while I was able to provide a provider network per the link, I cannot associate an instance to it. When I launch the instance I get the error "Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "blog-prod-1", the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance 6683be17-098e-450b-847a-3a36d8dc5e21.]."

Comment: Check out the nova-compute.log on the compute node where the instance failed. Also increase debug level for nova-scheduler and nova-conductor to see why it's failing. I assume that your compute node is missing the respective neutron configuration, perhaps `bridge_mappings`.

Comment: Thanks!! I ended up rebuilding the system and then following what I learned through these posts and it worked so I would classify my post as SOLVED. Unfortunately, I still cannot ping or ssh into instances on the provider network from my home network. I will start a new thread on that. Really appreciate your help and that of katonalala.

Answer (score 0):

have you used devstack (https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack) as installation script?
By the exception you need a physical network mapped as provider, so:

- create a bridge (I suppose you use OVS, but OVN is similar):
  ** ovs-vsctl add-br prov_bridge
- Edit the ml2_conf.ini (in my env it is under /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2), and add the new bridge to bridge_mappings:
  bridge_mappings = public:br-ex,provider:prov_bridge
  and check the ml2_type_flat section:
  [ml2_type_flat]
  flat_networks = public,provider

For OVN you can find some hints in this thread:
https://lists.openstack.org/pipermail/openstack-discuss/2023-March/032595.html

Comment: Really appreciate the help! I should preface this all with I am an OpenStack noob. I did use the devstack script to install on the VM. I issued the OVS command as you provided as the user stack but needed to sudo it for the command to not complain about permissions. I edited the file using the examples you provided and reran the command in my original post. Same result.

Comment: Have you restarted the Neutron services? sudo systemctl restart *q-* (You can check the service names with runnung systemctl without arguments, and in devstack for historical reasons Neutron services are q-svc q-agt or similar)

Comment: I restarted the service with sudo systemctl restart devstack@q-svc.service and reran the command in my original post with the same results.